# Tensorflow custom object detector numpy error

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I've been working through the tutorial at https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html trying to make an object detector. I've been through all the steps I believe correctly, but when I run the train commmand...

python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn --pipeline_config_path=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn/pipeline.config

...in my conda prompt this is the error. I'm including the end of the traceback. I can give more if need be.

...
File "pycocotools_mask.pyx", line 1, in init pycocotools._mask
ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject

I don't know what binary incompatibility is, and every other SO post I've seen regarding this error wants it to be a mismatch somewhere between versions of libraries I've pipped. That may still be what it is, but I've gone through a bunch of different version combinations trying to get it going and no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out this error, anyway. I reinstalled all of the pip libraries I had installed.

```
pip freeze --local >pipfreeze.txt
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall -r pipfreeze.txt
```

That seems to have fixed it. I have other errors later in the process now, so this may not be the final solution for someone else, but that's that.